# Global variable resets in google script when working with html

Tags: google-apps-script

why does global variable resets in google script, when working with html?
How can this be prevented?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In gs project files variables outside of functions are redeclared every time you call a function.  The only time I've found that not to be true is with recursive functions.  Try using [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) or [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service)

Comment: If @Cooper doesn't mind, I'd like to add some more details. Google Apps Script executions are stateless (outside of the Property or Cache service he mentioned). In the case of side bars, the GAS code is run when the sidebar is requested/invoked. When the sidebar is done loading the code exits. Whatever variables were set while it was running (while it was rendering the sidebar) is gone. So then, after the sidebar has loaded, if you do something that runs a function in the GAS code, it's running the whole code/project again. I hope that make sense?